# e.keyCode is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm making commenting system using jquery and php. The thing is the e.keycode is not working...it is directly taking to the php page but I just want it to just send the data and remain in the page...(I'm using handlebars for templating) following is my code:

the markup:

```
<form id="insert_comments" action="insert_comments.php" method="POST">
//the comment
<input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="add your comment.." />

//the post_id where the comment is passed
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{post_id}}"/>


//this is the $_GET['user'] variable here I'm displaying a number 
 //so I'm using get_user function to get the full name using the number
<input type="hidden" name="to_user" id="to_user" value="<?php echo     get_user('roll_no',"$get_user",'fullname','users'); ?>"/>
</form>
```

the jquery:

```
//the object named as comment
var comment = {

//the function which handles all operations which accepts config methods as parameters 
 init: function(config){
this.config = config;

//trigger  the events methos in this object
this.events();

 },

 //the event function
 events: function(){

  //the area of the comment text box
  this.config.textarea.keyup(function(e){

   //if the key is enter key

  if(e.keyCode==13 ){

 //here we are preventing default of that area so it won't jump to other page but it's not working!!


 e.preventDefault();

 //this var is created for using the this word

 var self = comment;

 //the ajax call
 $.ajax({
 url: self.config.url,
 type: "POST",

 data: self.config.form.serialize(),
 success: function(data){
  //on success just console.logging the result...
 console.log(data);

 }
 }); //end of ajax
 } //end of if statement

 }); //end of the event keyup
 } //end of this method

 };//end of this object

comment.init({
 form: $("#insert_comments"),\
 textarea: $("#comment"),
 url: "insert_comments.php"
 });
```

Comment: You really should check out code indentation ;)

Comment: jQuery event gives you a normalized property [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) which can be used to detect the pressed key, so instead of `keyCode` use `if(e.which==13 ){`

Comment: You do realize there are several syntax errors in the posted code. Did you open the console and check for errors.

Comment: there is no errors in the console..

Comment: You also gotta look up how to comment code properly. This is straight out horrible.

Comment: why?? i explained every single lines.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery standardizes all of the DOM 0, 1, and 2 handlers, because they are all wildly different. `keyCode` will work on some browsers, but not others. Instead, just use `e.which`, which jQuery standardizes cross-browser.

Comment: still it's not working...!!! i prepended an alert('enter key is presed') before the ajax call still is's not working!!...

Answer (score 0):

Your form is already submitted at the key*down*, so it is too late when you use key*up*. Replace keyup by keydown and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4LsrE/

```
// the object named as comment
var comment = {

  // the function which handles all operations which accepts config methods as parameters 
  init: function (config) {
    this.config = config;

    // trigger  the events methos in this object
    this.events();
  },

  // the event function
  events: function () {

    // the area of the comment text box
    this.config.textarea.keydown(function (e) {

      // if the key is enter key
      if (e.which === 13) {

        // here we are preventing default of that area so it won't jump to other page but it's not working!!
        e.preventDefault();

        // this var is created for using the this word
        var self = comment;

        // the ajax call
        $.ajax({
          url: self.config.url,
          type: "POST",

          data: self.config.form.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            // on success just console.logging the result...
            console.log(data);
          }
        }); // end of ajax
      } // end of if statement

    }); // end of the event keyup
  } // end of this method
}; // end of comment

comment.init({
  form: $("#insert_comments"),
  textarea: $("#comment"),
  url: "insert_comments.php"
});
```

Comment: Which effect do you mean? In the fiddle I posted above, you will stay on the current page and will not be redirected to the form's target ...?

Comment: the fiddle is working but when i use it in my file it again redirects to that page insert_comments.php

Comment: Did you modify anything? For example, you should not alert() anything, this could lead to problems.

Comment: ya i get it :D as it is a form chrome is submitting it when the enter key is pressed

Comment: Right but ```e.preventDefault()``` should prevent Chrome from submitting the form. I thought that was your question? ;)

Comment: ya it's not working, anyway i figured it out :D as i'm using handlebars it won't with the elements inside the script tags, so i have to do $(//the parent node before the script tags).on("keydown","#id of the comment",function(e){//submit})